# How to split the string obtained from "Time.now" in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
A=Time.now
```

gives following output:

```
2012:05:18 12:20:50 +0530
```

I want to form a string like `"May 18 , 2012"`. I tried changing `A` to string which was not possible. How can I achieve this?

Comment: User lowercase letters for variables as uppercase letters use to be constants.

Comment: @Kalyan: You should accept either of the correct answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Time.now.strftime('%b %e , %Y')
```

[More info](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime).

Comment: Thanks . But it gives "May 18 , 12". I want "May 18 , 2012"

Comment: It's %Y, not %y, %y will give you 12.

Answer (score 4):

You can have a look at the `Time` Class, and method `strftime`.
It formats time according to the directives in the given format string.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime

For your current problem:

`Time.now.strftime("%b %d, %Y")`